# How to change default example in ckeditor MathJax popup

Tags: ckeditor, mathjax

So i am looking to change the default example shown in the ckeditor mathjax popup as seen here: http://ckeditor.com/apps/ckeditor/4.4.0/samples/plugins/mathjax/mathjax.html (in the editor click on the mathjax toolbar button). The default example is always: "x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}"

however i want to change it to: "\cfrac{1}{2}"

My users are not experienced with mathjax so i just want them to see this simple example so they can make fractions. (the default example uses "1 \over 2" instead of the desired "\cfrac{1}{2}"

im using this as my mathjax library:

```
    CKEDITOR.config.mathJaxLib = '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML';
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into the ckeditor plugins folder and search the plugin "mathematical formulas" in the latter you will have a plugin.js file.

Edit it, the default formula is on line 49/50/51.

I hope to have helped you.

Comment: I tried this, but i think the problem is that in newer version of CKEditor you have to set the mathjax library as an external link:http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_mathjax-section-setting-the-path-to-mathjax-library "in order to enable the Mathematical Formulas plugin, you need to configure the CKEDITOR.config.mathJaxLib"

this means i dont think its using my local version of mathjax but rather this external one, which means i cant edit the plugin

Comment: never mind i didnt read the guide properly. i can set the mathjax library as my local one. I changed :
CKEDITOR.config.mathJaxLib = '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML';
to my local one